# The Big-$\mathcal{O}$ notation

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

Suppose that you take out a $\$15,000$ loan to purchase a car. The loan has an interest rate of $3\%$ per year, compounded monthly.

The formula for the amount of interest accrued over a time period $T$ measured in number of months is

$$f(x) =15,000\left(1+\frac{0.03}{12}\right)^T-15,000$$ 
Use a quadratic approximation to approximate the amount of interest accrued over 4 years.

the approximation for $T=48$
$$f(48) \approx -15,000+15,000(1+0.12+0.007)+ \mathcal{O}(x^3)$$
Then I need to find.

1. The error in the of this formula approximation is $\mathcal{O}(x^3)$. Find the order of magnitude of $x^3$ in our problem.
2. Compute the exact error term in the quadratic approximation.
3. Use the error to identify the order of magnitude of $k$ since the error is known to be $kx^3$.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Note that $(1+c)^x \approx 1+cx +c^2x(x-1)/2+c^3x(x-1)(x-2)/6+...$.

Comment: You have a $T$ and an $x$ ... do you know the relationship between them?

Comment: they are the same. $T$ is the $x$ in equation.